# WkWebview local site Access Origin

Tags: ios, swift, cors

[image]

i have the following application as, the folder structure is as the picture above.

Then i load this `index.html` in the following way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate{
      var webView: WKWebView!

     override func loadView() {
         webView = WKWebView()
         view = webView
     }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "iosbuild")!
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)

        
    }
}
```

When inspecting this in my Safari browser I get an `access-origin` error:

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What have I done wrong? or how I might change the URL to allow the load of my assets / scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the exact same code with your folder structure and this worked for me so I think this error originates from the html content.

Try and see if any of these help you:

**Set he allow read access on the directory**

```
// I added
let directoryURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("iosbuild")

// your code
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index",
                          withExtension: "html",
                          subdirectory: "iosbuild")!

// changed read access
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: directoryURL)
```

**This could be CORS related, so add a webview configuration**

```
// Configure this before instantiating web views
// Worked for me in the past with CORS errors
let configs = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configs.setValue(true, forKey: "_allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")

let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configs)
self.view.addSubview(webView)

// rest of your delegate set up
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true

// your code
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index",
                          withExtension: "html",
                          subdirectory: "iosbuild")!

// this is back to your own code but if it doesn't work
// you can try allowing the read access on the directory like before
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
```

Give these a go and see if this gives you any luck

Comment: The active ingredient in all this is setting `_allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs`. But setting private properties is likely to cause the app to be rejected. An alternative is to use GCDWebServer and load local content via `http://localhost`.

Comment: other alt is to use a custom url scheme to serve assets