# IOS WkWebview local content set base URL

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Currently when loading a local html file it gets a really long URL:

like such:

```
Users/marcrasmussen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/....../index.html"
```

This is fairly annoying when some of my `JavaScript` is checking the url for `routing`.

Is it possible to set a base url of the `WkWebview`? an example would be `app.mr.dk`

Here is how i set the file to load:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "iosbuild")!
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: directoryURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/radianttap/HTML2PDFRenderer

Try this, You can display HTML and also generate pdf

[WkWebview local site Access Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910805/wkwebview-local-site-access-origin)

some answers here is code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).